# Can we have just interface in Nuget Package Creation?

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I have 2 Projects.

There is one interface `IMHandler` which has 2 methods -

```
bool IsValid(Message m)

void Handel(Message m, Callback callback)
```

In 1st project, there is one class `MHandler` which implements `IMHandler`. In 2nd project there are 4 classes that implement `MHandler`. And the implementation is different in Project 1 and 2.

We are planning to create Nuget Package for reusability. Which is the best approach for above scenario ?

1. Create 2 separate Nuget Packages for both the projects for `MHandler`, because the implementation is different in both. Both the packages will have Interface and their corresponding classes.
2. Create a common Nuget Package for both projects and include only Interface in it. The classes will be a part of the Project because of different implementation. Including only interface in Nuget package..is it a good design ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question - create 2 seperate Nuget Packages for both the projects because the implementation is different in both. Very basic reason being difference in implementation.